# Drupal 8 project in netbeans invalid include path

Tags: netbeans, drupal-8

I'm running drupal 8 from latest git sources. When I open it Netbeans 8 and 8.1 beta, both give me error "Invalid include path - Some directories on project's Include Path are invalid." 
Due to this error intellisense is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is Drupal but an advice to them who use Laravel: rid off any path-shmath and leave it emty like this:[image]

hit ok and now project will going to open much faster.